"conda env create -f environment.yml" -- solving environment failed
I am attempting to implement a BNN posted on GitHub in the link attached: https://github.com/yucenli/bnn-bo.
In the README section, I tried running code "conda env create -f environment.yml", which is supposed to be the part where I create a new conda environment. However, my terminal returned the following error message:
PS C:\Users\liuna> conda env create -f environment.yml
Channels:
 - pytorch
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Channels:
 - pytorch
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested zlib ==1.2.13 h5eee18b_0
  - nothing provides requested zeromq ==4.3.4 h9c3ff4c_1
  - nothing provides requested xz ==5.4.2 h5eee18b_0
  - nothing provides requested wheel ==0.38.4 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested typing_extensions ==4.5.0 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested traitlets ==5.7.1 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested tornado ==6.1 py39hb9d737c_3
  - nothing provides requested tk ==8.6.12 h1ccaba5_0
  - nothing provides requested sqlite ==3.41.2 h5eee18b_0
  - nothing provides requested setuptools ==67.8.0 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested readline ==8.2 h5eee18b_0
  - nothing provides requested pyzmq ==19.0.2 py39hb69f2a1_2
  - nothing provides requested python ==3.9.16 h7a1cb2a_2
  - nothing provides requested pygments ==2.15.1 py39h06a4308_1
  - nothing provides requested prompt-toolkit ==3.0.36 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested pip ==23.0.1 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested pcre ==8.45 h295c915_0
  - nothing provides requested openssl ==1.1.1t h7f8727e_0
  - nothing provides requested ncurses ==6.4 h6a678d5_0
  - nothing provides requested matplotlib-inline ==0.1.6 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides requested libstdcxx-ng ==11.2.0 h1234567_1
  - nothing provides requested libsodium ==1.0.18 h36c2ea0_1
  - nothing provides requested libgomp ==11.2.0 h1234567_1
  - nothing provides requested libgcc-ng ==11.2.0 h1234567_1
  - nothing provides requested libffi ==3.4.4 h6a678d5_0
  - nothing provides requested ld_impl_linux-64 ==2.38 h1181459_1
  - nothing provides requested jupyter_core ==4.12.0 py39hf3d152e_0
  - nothing provides requested jedi ==0.18.1 py39h06a4308_1
  - nothing provides requested ipython ==8.12.0 py39h06a4308_0
  - nothing provides __linux needed by ipykernel-6.15.0-pyh210e3f2_0
  - nothing provides requested debugpy ==1.5.1 py39h295c915_0
  - nothing provides requested ca-certificates ==2023.5.7 hbcca054_0
  - nothing provides requested _openmp_mutex ==5.1 1_gnu

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ _openmp_mutex ==5.1 1_gnu does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missi;
├─ ca-certificates ==2023.5.7 hbcca054_0 does not exist (perhaps a typ;
├─ debugpy ==1.5.1 py39h295c915_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a ;
├─ ipykernel ==6.15.0 pyh210e3f2_0 is not installable because it requis
│  └─ __linux, which is missing on the system;
├─ ipython ==8.12.0 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a;
├─ jedi ==0.18.1 py39h06a4308_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a mi;
├─ jupyter_core ==4.12.0 py39hf3d152e_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo;
├─ ld_impl_linux-64 ==2.38 h1181459_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo o;
├─ libffi ==3.4.4 h6a678d5_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missi;
├─ libgcc-ng ==11.2.0 h1234567_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a m;
├─ libgomp ==11.2.0 h1234567_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a mis;
├─ libsodium ==1.0.18 h36c2ea0_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a m;
├─ libstdcxx-ng ==11.2.0 h1234567_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or ;
├─ matplotlib-inline ==0.1.6 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a ;
├─ ncurses ==6.4 h6a678d5_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missin;
├─ openssl ==1.1.1t h7f8727e_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a mis;
├─ pcre ==8.45 h295c915_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing ;
├─ pip ==23.0.1 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a mis;
├─ prompt-toolkit ==3.0.36 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a ty;
├─ pygments ==2.15.1 py39h06a4308_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or ;
├─ python ==3.9.16 h7a1cb2a_2 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a miss;
├─ pyzmq ==19.0.2 py39hb69f2a1_2 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a m;
├─ readline ==8.2 h5eee18b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missi;
├─ setuptools ==67.8.0 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo o;
├─ sqlite ==3.41.2 h5eee18b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a miss;
├─ tk ==8.6.12 h1ccaba5_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing ;
├─ tornado ==6.1 py39hb9d737c_3 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a mi;
├─ traitlets ==5.7.1 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or ;
├─ typing_extensions ==4.5.0 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a ;
├─ wheel ==0.38.4 py39h06a4308_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a m;
├─ xz ==5.4.2 h5eee18b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing c;
├─ zeromq ==4.3.4 h9c3ff4c_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missi;
└─ zlib ==1.2.13 h5eee18b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missin.

I have also attempted codes like "conda update conda" to ensure everything's up to date, and it looks like some packages aren't compatible or do not exist but this entire environment should be created fairly recent and I believe it has nothing to do with specific versions (i.e. if anything, wouldn't the versions above be just old but not necessarily nonexistent?). I have looked up this issue and do not think I see a similar problem being actually answered. Perhaps there is a straightforward fix to this. Thanks in advance.
Mentioned above (e.g. attempted running "conda update conda".)

You are trying to create a Linux environment on a Windows machine.  The package specs are going to be different.
